# str_replace inside fct_reorder inside mutate(across())

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-factor, across

Say I have this tibble:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~how_bright_txt, ~how_bright_num,   ~how_hard_txt, ~how_hard_num, ~how_hot_txt, ~how_hot_num,
  "Not very much",              1L,   "Really hard",            5L,       "Cold",           1L,
       "Somewhat",              2L, "Somewhat hard",            2L, "A bit cold",           2L,
         "Medium",              3L,        "Medium",            3L,     "Medium",           3L,
    "Quite a bit",              4L,    "Quite hard",            4L,  "Quite hot",           4L,
          "A lot",              5L, "Not very hard",            1L, "Really hot",           5L
  )
```

I want to make new columns named with the first part of the existing column names (minus the `_txt` or `_num` prefix) and which take the value of the `_txt` columns but converting them to factors ordered by the corresponding `_num` columns.

I can do this by repeating `fct_reorder` inside `mutate` for each column, like so:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    mutate(how_bright = fct_reorder(how_bright_txt, -how_bright_num),
           how_hard = fct_reorder(how_hard_txt, -how_hard_num),
           how_hot = fct_reorder(how_hot_txt, -how_hot_num)) %>%
    select(-c(ends_with("_txt"), ends_with("_num")))
```

But I want to streamline this and use `mutate(across())`. So I tried doing this:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("_txt"), 
         ~ fct_reorder(.x, str_replace(.x, "_txt", "_num")), 
                     .names = '{stringr::str_remove({col}, "_txt")}')) %>%
    select(-c(ends_with("_txt"), ends_with("_num")))
```

But **the ordering of the resulting factors (`how_bright`, `how_hard`, `how_hot`) are incorrect** and don't correspond to the ordering in the original `_num` columns. I have also tried replacing the `str_replace` call with a `gsub` call but I get the same output

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `cur_column()` and `get()`. `cur_column()` gives the current column name, i.e. `*_txt`. After `str_replace()` is used on it, `get()` searches the new name (i.e. `*_num`) in the current dataset and returns its values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("_txt"), 
                ~ fct_reorder(.x, get(str_replace(cur_column(), "_txt", "_num"))),
                .names = "{str_remove(.col, '_txt')}"),
         .keep = "unused")

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   how_bright    how_hard      how_hot   
#   <fct>         <fct>         <fct>     
# 1 Not very much Really hard   Cold      
# 2 Somewhat      Somewhat hard A bit cold
# 3 Medium        Medium        Medium    
# 4 Quite a bit   Quite hard    Quite hot 
# 5 A lot         Not very hard Really hot
```

Comment: @C.Robin I update some description.